# AES Decrypter not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I have the following password (which is already encrypted) and key

password = bbSOvqxMRpO004qYLD/REQ==

key = VUzwYCbBBcEQxu6jvGrwnvAYCD2d7FpQ

The following code is returning not properly padded
for the decrypted password and I'm not really sure why. After looking at several examples I seem to be following them.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public abstract class AESDecrypter {

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedString, String key) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = null;
            Cipher decryptCipher = null;
            //----
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = null;
        Cipher decryptCipher = null;
        //----
        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        System.out.println(keySpec.toString());
        decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
        System.out.println("End decrypt");
        return new String(decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString.getBytes("UTF-8"))), "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

returns

```
Given final block not properly padded
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
        at edu.uga.ovpr.decrypter.AESDecrypter.decrypt(AESDecrypter.java:35)
        at edu.uga.ovpr.filetransferrer.FTPSConnection.<init>(FTPSConnection.java:44)
        at edu.uga.ovpr.filetransferrer.FileTransferrer.getConnection(FileTransferrer.java:285)
        at edu.uga.ovpr.filetransferrer.FileTransferrer.doTransfer(FileTransferrer.java:221)
        at edu.uga.ovpr.filetransferrer.FileTransferrer.main(FileTransferrer.java:128)
```

Comment: Well how about you don't just swallow exceptions... I strongly suspect that an exception is being thrown, but you're losing *all* the information from it. You should very rarely catch `Exception` anyway (prefer to catch specific exceptions) and almost *never* just return a value without even logging the exception. (The `new String(...)` part *definitely* won't return `null`.)

Comment: Ok. I've removed the try and catch block.  Now I get a 

Given final block not properly padded

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)

        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
        at edu.uga.ovpr.decrypter.AESDecrypter.decrypt(AESDecrypter.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

use bouncycastle lib 
simplest & faster with more cipher modes of  AES : http://bouncycastle.org